# Why is $-\frac{1}{a \pi \alpha}\left[\frac{\cos(2 \pi \alpha x)}{2 \pi \alpha}\right]_0^{a}= \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha a)}{\pi \alpha}$?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

$$-\frac{1}{a \pi \alpha}\left[\frac{\cos(2 \pi \alpha x)}{2 \pi \alpha}\right]_0^{a}= \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha a)}{\pi \alpha}$$

I've been trying to figure this out but I can't seem to find which trigonometric properties to use.

Comment: I've edited your post to fix some of the formatting, could you check it's still what you meant?

Comment: The half-angle formula   $(\cos 2y)-1=(-1+2cos^2y)-1=-2(1-\cos^2 y)=-2\sin^2 y$...... with  $y=\pi \alpha x$.

Comment: is this equation from an integral?

Comment: what is the original Problem?

Answer (score 0):

For what is given is:
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{a \pi \alpha} \, \left[\frac{\cos(2 \pi \alpha x)}{2 \pi \alpha}\right]_{0}^{a} &= \frac{1 - \cos(2 \pi \alpha a)}{2 \, a \, (\pi \alpha)^{2}} = \frac{a \, \sin^{2}(\pi \alpha a)}{(\pi \alpha a)^{2}},
\end{align}
since $2 \sin^{2}(x) = 1 - \cos(2 x)$.